# windows phone development on windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, compatibility, windows-8

Apparently there is no support for XP when it comes to WP7 development (even though visual studio 2010 still works on xp).  As I do most of my work on linux now, I think it is a bit wasteful to go out and buy windows 7 just for the WP7 sdk.

My question: If I upgrade my xp install to the windows 8 consumer preview (which seems to be free), will I be able to install and use the windows phone SDK?

I read all kind of stories on the internet, some say it does, other it doesn't.

Comment: Be aware that eventhough the consumer preview is free it contains a timebomb and is beta. Also check the XP hardware to see if it can run Windows 7/8 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/faq

Comment: is there anything new in this ? for iOS developement, one needs to have a Mac. and people have done that, bought a macbook just for iOS dev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Windows Phone development is supported on Windows 8 CP. You will have to download the [7.1.1 update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233) and install it on top of the 7.1 SDK for the emulator to work, though.